# TCP port mapping / proxy with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, proxy, tcp

I have several services running on a single AWS instance on different ports:

- rabbit   :5672
- rabbitMQ :15672
- elastic  :9200
- a few others

I have a jumpbox on AWS which handles all incoming requests. I had looked into HAProxy on the jumpbox but a pure AWS solution would be better.

The end goal here is to point incoming requests on standard ports based on their subdomains to potentially separate instances internally or the same instance with different ports:

eg.

a request to `staging.example.com:5672` would go to instance `A:5672`

a request to `development.example.com:5672` would go to `A:5673`

I'm looking for a solution using the AWS stack, but struggled to find something applicable. Since rabbit uses the amqp protocol, http hostname resolution does not appear to be an option, and as far as I can tell there is no simple straight incoming_hostname:incoming_port -> instance:port mapping using the ELB, but I am very new to the AWS stack.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. Is your "jumpbox" a reverse proxy or a bastion host? Are you looking for a suggestion on how to set up a reverse proxy to services on a single machine with the services running on different ports?

Comment: @Tim whoops - it's a bastion host. The current setup has 2 environments on the same machine running duplicate services on different ports (ie default and default + 1). Normally, this would be trivial with separate endpoints for each environment (ie multiple bastion hosts OR reverse proxies), but for the time being I just wanted to see if it was an easy solution to run both env's on the same vpc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that "might" do what you want is using ELB+Lambda to process those requests, but it's not worth the effort.

The proper way would be to use nginx or haproxy as you've already mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, I was worried that might be the case. I think a slight re-architecture and nginx and/or haproxy is the way to go.